# Can't acces my firebase api classes with intelliJ IDE

Tags: firebase, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, dependency-management

I'm building a desktop App in Kotlin with IntelliJ IDE and I'm struggling to add dependency in this environement. This is my 'build.gradle.kts' file :

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        jvmToolchain(11)
        withJava()
    }
    sourceSets {
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                // Firebase dependencies I added 
                implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0")
                implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.2.0")

                implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting
    }
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "KaraokeAppAdminControl"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

The build completed successfully but I am unable to import `com.google.firebase.database` or `com.google.firebase.auth` into my other Kotlin files and I don't know why. I also noticed that the Firebase dependencies downloaded were different from the ones I already had. They have this .aar file extension and I don't know what it means:

[image: external libraries screenshot]

Comment: I succesfully add implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.1.1") in my gradle depencies but it does not completely fit my needs. Any advices ?